# how can I update the path to Android Studio?

Tags: launcher, android

I was using Android studio 1.5. I fired up the studio and then locked it to the launcher. That made it very easy to fire up from there on.

Now I just updated to 2.0. I unlocked the first icon from the launcher, went to the 2.0 directory and used ./studio.sh. As expected, up came version 2.0. Great, now to lock it to the launcher bar. Done. Exit the studio and press the icon. What comes up? Good ole 1.5 which I no longer want to use.

There must be some sort of path variable which I am not finding. What I got from printenv is

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

which clearly has no reference to either version of Android studio. So where does the icon on the launch bar get its location from? How can I update it to the new location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Go to the installation dir, and fire it up with `./studio.sh`

2-A) **[For > v2.0]** There is an option to add a shortcut in Android Studio's "main menu":
[image]

---

2-B) **[For < v2.0]** There is an option to add a shortcut in Android Studio's "main menu":
[image]

Comment: Great answer which I hope will help others. The only "problem" is that you are using the version I upgraded from. In 2.0 it no longer appears where you show it. Instead there is a configure wheel at the bottom and it is one of the options. (I may have used the desktop entry when I started with 1.5.1 but I no longer remember.) In any case your answer is very much to the point.